# Blog design improvement request, tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, blog

So it seems that administration request on the blog has to be posted here, so.

On the blog there is currently no mention of categories and tags in articles.

You can browse categories via the "Topics" navigation on the right, but there is no way to tell if the current article belongs to `review` category, or is listed in the `multi-player` tag.

We are currently trying to get a correct tagging system to improve user readability, but this is currently going nowhere since users can't see them.

So, could we turn this on?

Comment: I'm fixing this very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories and tags are now displayed with the post excerpts on the main page, and also underneath the post when viewing a single post.